# How to start and setup Ruby On Rails development with eclipse

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having excellent experience in Java and eclipse, But new to Ruby on Rails, can anyone point to the best resources, or step which i can follow to start with Ruby On Rails development and enviornment setup for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Rails Tutorial` is a best place for you to start learning, setup environment and development for Ruby on Rails:

- [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)
- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and about [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)
- Some videos [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/)
- Book [Rails 3 way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661)

One more thing, I think many Rails developers will not build Rails application on Window.

Comment: Kien, i have checked your links, but not able to find anything about starting it with eclipse

Comment: Actually, I don't think Eclipse (or some other tools like RubyMine) is good tool for development Ruby on Rails, because they usually change some config, if you forget and can't found it, you will have pain head. all you need is just a text editor. You can read here for more discussing [IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91445/best-ide-for-ruby-on-rails). Currently, I use Sublime Text 2 and I find it works great, I think Rails developers use it will think like me.

Comment: I have started it using Aptana

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it fine. You just have to setup the correct run config to run rails -s